# jQuery "working partially" in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to use jQuery to change some css when the screen is smaller than a certain size (basically, this is a re-implementation of "@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)", but I am under the impression that this doesn't work in older versions of IE, and I need it to).

This is working in all browsers but IE (ironically).  It is "partially" working in IE (so it's not anything super fundamental like jQuery isn't installed correctly).  Some css gets changed properly.  Other parts do not appear to be changed at all... but when I spit the values out on the console, they do appear to be changed.

Here is the code:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 1154) {
            $(".a").css("display", "none");
            $(".b").css("right", "0px");
        } else {
            $(".a").css("display", "inline");
            $(".b").each(
                function (itemIndex, item) {
                    var a = $(item).parents(".c").children(".a");
                    $(item).css("right", a.css("width"));
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

The idea is, when the screen is small, hide elements of class "a", and adjust elements of class "b" (which are to the left of "a" elements, and are also siblings to them, both under elements of class "c") so that they take up the empty space where the "a"s were.

"A" elements are hidden properly in all browsers.  In some versions of IE (9 and earlier I think), "b" elements' right property is not set correctly, and does not appear to change at all.  BUT, if I log the element id (each "b" has a unique id) and right property every time I change it, I get some unexpected results.  First of all, resize seems to be called twice every time I change the screen size (using the maximize/unmaximize button), which I'm assuming is just because multiple events get fired for some reason, so maybe not a big deal.  The weird thing is, when I make the screen smaller, the actual value of "right" after setting it is shown as 0 both times.  When I make the screen larger, the actualy value of "right" is shown as 0 the first time and 180 the second time (see below).  But as displayed on the page, the right value always looks like 180 and never 0.

```
setting b0 right=0px ... Actual value: 0px 
setting b0 right=0px ... Actual value: 0px 
setting b0 right=180px ... Actual value: 0px 
setting b0 right=180px ... Actual value: 180px 
setting b0 right=0px ... Actual value: 0px 
setting b0 right=0px ... Actual value: 0px 
setting b0 right=180px ... Actual value: 0px 
setting b0 right=180px ... Actual value: 180px
```

It should also be mentioned, if I examine the "right" properties in the HTML tab, it always says 180 (unsurprisingly).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? Although I did not investigate further yet maybe it helps to know that "jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8"

Comment: Last I knew, we were on jQuery 1.6  Good to know though!

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for it? It may help me or others to help you :)

Comment: When I started working on this jsfiddle thing (which is pretty neat), I found something that may be the problem:   

<!--[if IE]>
  <style type="text/css">
    #b0 {
        width: expression(this.offsetParent.clientWidth - 220 - 180 + "px");
    }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->

Comment: Nice! That's what it is for :)

Comment: BTW: I think one should always avoid CSS expressions - in my eyes they were always something bad and were even not implemented well regarding security and performance ... and nowadays they're also considered a bad idea by Microsoft as they are deprecated since IE8

Answer (score 0):

As I hope that you could actually solve your problem based on my comments I'll consolidate them to this answer:

Although you have provided a detailed description and respective code snippets to your problem, your question can be improved by also **providing e.g. a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** - this is a very good practice as one needs to isolate specific problems to the relevant components. At least it is a very good way to give others easy access to it and the possibility to help. You can then just save your JSFiddle and post the permanent link to it along your question at SO.

Regarding the actual topic:

When working with libraries it is always a good starting point to **check incompatibilities** regarding the respective target platform(s) - especially when targeting very old versions of something and **even more when it is about Internet Explorer**.

So it is with jQuery - as stated on their homepage: "jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8". Although it was not the reason for the issue here it well may have been.

As you found out by yourself when fiddling around with your code **the actual problem seemed to be the specific IE CSS expression** - so allow me to note that in my eyes one should always avoid CSS expressions where possible. They are **deprecated** since IE8 and are not supported anymore. They were considered a **bad idea** by many in terms of security and performance implications.